# azure availability set second VM shuts down first VM

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, availability

I've got two Ubuntu VMs in one availability set. When I start the second VM it takes a few minutes and the first VM stopps. 
I'm a bit helpless (beginner) here. Any advice would be very apprechiated.

Comment: Have you enabled Auto-Scale as well as an availability set? This would explain why one of the VMs is shutting down after a 2nd VM is added to the Availability set.

Comment: Yes, autoscale is enabled. But as soon as the first VM gets shut down the things I'm running on it are not available anymore. Also, I had it running like this before, my VMs were shut down because of an error in the billing procedure. After that I couldn't return to the previous status.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like autoscale is shutting down your VM. Autoscale will look at the current CPU Usage and shutdown one of the VMs if it is not required. in this case it is choosing to shutdown a VM you need. If you need both VMs running then you can disable Auto-scale, this will keep your VMs running. Or you can try to adjust the autoscale settings to try and keep both VMs running.